# Topic - How do I check app name availability with new iTunes Connect?

Tags: app-store-connect, itunes

In the old iTunes connect, you could go to 'add app' only fill out the App Name field, and it would return telling you if the app name is taken or not. Now iTunes connect makes you fill out the bundle id, version, sku etc. before pressing submit. So if the app name is free, it automatically makes you create it.

Is there any way to check without adding more apps to my iTunes Connect page? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your app has been created in iTunes connect, than the name is most likely available, or it probably wouldn't have let you create it. If you want to double check though, here are two solutions:

-You could try searching the app store for your app name. If the search results turn up no apps with your name it is available.

-If your name is not available you could add "for iPhone" or "for iPad" to the end of your app name, which is an easy way of using an already taken name.

Hope this helps!

Comment: "-You could try searching the app store for your app name. If the search results turn up no apps with your name it is available." this is, unfortunately, wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by filling all the fields with placeholders (images, texts) but with the real name you wish to use.

If it lets you create it, then it is available. After that, you can use the app at iTunes Connect to upload your builds, replace those placeholders with the final keywords, description, images, etc and submit for review.